# What is the correct method call?

Tags: java, methods

Sorry, I'm just learning the basics of Java.

If my header is:

```
public static int bar(int j, ArrayList<String> arr)
```

Would any of these be a correct way to call the method?

```
int bar(j, arr);
bar(int j, ArrayList<String> arr);
int bar(int j, ArrayList<String> arr);
int i = bar(j, arr);
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, why don't you test it? Or if you're having an error message please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and error message.

Comment: I agree with just trying it out. If your code doesn't compile, the compiler error messages will often tell you what's wrong. Similarly if it compiles but doesn't run, how it doesn't run should be informative. And if after all that there's still something you don't get, post more code (preferably a small, working (or what you think should be working) example). What you've posted above isn't enough to say whether your method call is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

First, for your 4 examples, only one of them are method calls.

```
int i = bar(j, arr);
```

For this particular call, it heavily depends on the the context you are calling the method in. For example, if you have a simple class `Test` with the method inside the class you can call it like that.

```
package test;

public class Test {

    public static int bar(int j) {
        return j + 2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = bar(0); // a = 2
    }

}
```

However, suppose you are trying to call it from a different class within the same package.

```
package test;

public class TestTwo {

    public void foobar()
    {
        int a = bar(0); // error.
    }

}
```

You will now have to specify which `bar` you are referring to.

```
int a = Test.bar(0); // a = 2
```

However, if you could also use [static import](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) as [blm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5349263/blm) mentioned.

By adding something like

```
import static test.Test.bar;
```

You could once again call `bar` with just `bar()`.

Note however, that if `bar` was not `static`, you would be in a completely different scenario.

Suppose we have a method `foo` that is not `static`.

```
package test;

public class Test {

    public int foo(int i) {
        return i + 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = foo(1); // error
    }

}
```

You will instead have to call `foo` by creating a new instance of `Test`.

```
int i = new Test().foo(1); // 2
```

Comment: Not necessarily, there isn't really any way to tell whether the code in the original post is correct because there's not enough context. I could put the two snippets in code that would work fine, or code that wouldn't even compile. Also, your answer is just wrong (unless using a very old Java, pre-5.0), bar is public so it just needs to be in a class accessible to the code calling it and imported correctly (via a static import (which I tend not to like, but would work)), for example a completely different public class in a completely separate package.

Comment: @blm honestly I have never used static import and didn't even know it is a thing. Thanks for correcting me. Learn something new every day.

Comment: You're welcome, it's good to learn something new every day. :-) And thanks for expanding your answer, it looks like a nice, complete answer now.